# Regex too much or none at all.

Tags: regex

Here is an example of the string I'm matching against.

```
<div class="unique"><a href="/2343242/link to something target="_self">"HERE IS THE TEXT 
I'D LIKE"</a></div>
```

This gets me way too much. As in it doesnt stop at the  and it seems to still return the div and a tags.

```
/(?:<div class="unique">)?(?:<a href=.*>)?.*(?:<)?/
```

This returns nothing

```
/(?:<div class="unique">)?(?:<a href=.*>)?.*(?:</a>)?/
```

So shouldn't the first part match against the unique "div" tag and the following "a" tag and not return them.  Then grab everything up until the first < that it hits which would be the closing "a" tag? I'm lost as to what is mucking this up.

Thank you.

Comment: Is your input guaranteed to _never_ have any nested `div`-s or other elements? If not, regex will be very, very hard (if not downright impossible) to use for this. HTML is not a regular language.

Comment: Whatever language you're using, it **has** a library for HTML parsing and manipulation. Use it and save yourself lots of pain and bitter disappointment.

Comment: There will never be any nested anything. The html will never change the form it is in above.  Already been down the html_simple_dom road and this is much easier in the long run.  Just trying to figure out the mistake in my statement.

Comment: why not using simpler pattern like [This](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/grv-nyx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this works better.

```
(?:<div class="unique">)(?:<a href=.*?>)?.*?(?:<.a>)
```

Works great.

Comment: Can be shortened to `/<div class="unique">(?:<a href=.*?>)?.*?<\/a>/`